# Using typedef as a shortcut for unsigned types in C

Tags: c, cross-platform, typedef

I'm writing a Chip-8 emulator in C, and my goal is to have it be compatible with as many different operating systems, new and old as possible I realize that a lot of different types for representing exact bit widths have been added over the years, so is something like this reasonable to both create a shortcut (so I don't have to write lots of unsigned chars/longs) and account for compilers that already have the numbers defined? If not, is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

```
#ifdef __uint8_t_defined
    typedef uint8_t uchar;
    typedef int8_t schar;
    typedef uint16_t ushort;
    typedef int16_t sshort;
#else
    typedef unsigned char uchar;
    typedef signed char schar;
    typedef unsigned short ushort;
    typedef signed short sshort;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall idea is reasonable - write portable code.  OP's approach is not.

1. `__uint8_t` is not defined by the C spec.  Using that to steer compilation for portable code can lead to unspecified behavior.  Better to use `..._MAX` definitions.
2. Code is creating types based on fixed width types on one platform and non-specified widths on another. Not a good plan.   Where code needs fixed width types, use fixed width types like `uint8_t`, etc.  Where code wants to use short-hand `uchar` for `unsigned char`, etc., use a `#define uchar unsigned char` or better `typedef unsigned char uchar;`.
3. Attempting to create portable integer code without `<stdint.h>` is folly.  Even compilers that do not natively have the file have on-line look alikes easily findable.

---

If user still wants to create `uchar` and friends like originally posted, suggest the more portable:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef INT_LEAST8_MAX
  typedef uint_least8_t uchar;
#else
  typedef unsigned char uchar;
#endif

#ifdef INT_LEAST16_MAX
  typedef uint_least16_t ushort;
...
```

Comment: This does improve portability, but it also creates the burden of always keeping in mind that objects might be larger than the minimum size.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a very good idea!  Never assume sizes for primitive types.  If you are writing portable code this is a must for maintainability!  This little trick will save tons of time and will help create a good foundation for maintaining a portable code base.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't make any assumptions on the sizes of the primitive types. Not even that `char` has 8 bits. Check this discussion:

[What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

I think standard integer types are pretty well-supported. If you don't have `stdint.h`, then your chances of cross-compatibility seem very dim to me. Expecting `stdint.h` to be available for the compiler seems like a reasonable pre-condition.